# BIOS ACPI Error message when installing OS on MSI-Z370-A PRO

Tags: boot, bios, bootable-media, acpi

I got a brand new MSI Z370-A PRO PC with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 and 1151 Socket. 
Currently, the hard drive is empty, when I try booting OS installation from an external medium (either USB or CD), I got this error:

[image: error during boot]

Error text:

```
[   0.161354] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/dswload2-191)
[   0.161360] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20160930/psobject-227)
[   0.161362] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.RP04.PXSX] (Node ffff89d3edcd85f0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
[   0.161572] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/dswload2-191)
[   0.161574] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20160930/psobject-227) 
[   0.161576] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.RP08.PXSX] (Node ffff89d3edcd9500), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/psparse-543)
```

After a few searches, I learnt that I need to disable the ACPI option from the BIOS; however, the only available option is 'LED/Blinking' which is not helpful (screen shot below ↓↓↓)

[image: bios]

(Sorry for the invisible text menu.)

As you can see from the screen capture; the current version has no support for flashing (Flash-M) and with the BIOS refusing to recognize all first-order media, I'll be grateful if anyone could direct me into a solution that can successfully make a USB/CD/DVD boot possible.

Comment: Your transcription of the first screen image is wrong — it goes straight from the fifth timestamp to the sixth line, and there is at least one obvious typo.  Please fix and double-check.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved the problem, sorry that I didn't post any updates.

The error appears because the ACPI option -unlike Windows- is not implemented in Ubuntu (17.04 at least).

You need to turn the acpi flag off from the grub; At boot screen, hit 'e' key, you will be redirected to the grub menu, add:

```
acpi=off
```

at the end of the **linux /vmlinuz** line. After that save the new settings and re-boot with **cntrl + X** and resume the installation.

This will work out assuming that the Secure Boot is disabled.

(I am setting this post as solved)

Comment: You're not fixing the error, you're just avoiding it

Comment: True, this workaround does not fix the error, but it -temporarily- solved the problem in hand. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you with a similar system trying to install Xubuntu 16.04. I was able to solve it by following these steps:

1. Go to GRUB menu and press '**e**' while highlighting the `Install Xubuntu` option.
2. Add `nomodeset acpi_osi=` after `quiet splash` (line starting with `linux`).
3. Press CTRL+x or F10 to boot.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/838369

I was able to install Xubuntu afterwards. However, after the installation I was only seeing a black screen. That problem was likely caused by a missing GPU driver. The following steps worked for me:

1. Go to GRUB menu and press '**e**' while highlighting `Ubuntu` (the one that usually boots the just installed Xubuntu/Ubuntu).
2. Replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.
3. Press CTRL+x or F10 to boot.
4. Install the missing (Nvidia) drivers.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/162076